I am trying to install Ubuntu with dualboot along Windows but linux is not loading after selecting in grub(Ubuntu studio and Kubuntu) version 24.04
I am a newbie trying to install Ubuntu on my new Asus tuf f15 laptop.
However, after installing and I remove my usb as instructed on the screen to restart - the system is not restarting forever.
If I try to force restart Linux loads for the first time but from then grub is showing and when I select Ubuntu, nothing happens just blank screen.
Searched a lot on internet but could not find anything. Can someone please please help me. (Please don't say that this question is dumb am trying hard to get started with Linux, till now I have installed many times with different flavours but facing the same issue)
Regards,
Vishwas
Edit: after reading some comments, adding more details (apologies for not mentioning them before).
System configuration: i5, 16gb ram, nvidia rtx 2050.SSD of 512gb.
Version: 24.04
Secure boot: turned off
There were no installation errors encountered.
I have selected option to install 3rd party software to get Nvidia graphics driver.
Also, it's loading properly to the same state if I go to advanced options and go through recovery option.
But the issue persists if I go through normal boot option.
Windows loads perfectly alright.
I tried installing nvidia drivers from secure boot session and it didn't work (I forgot the error that I got).
Many thanks for the support and all comments recieved..

If I try to force restart Linux loads for the first time Does the GUI load?

The question is not dumb, but it lacks a lot of information that "searched a lot on the internet" told you that we need up front. Secure Boot? Install errors? Non-default install options? Release of Ubuntu? Blinking cursor? Organization and types of storage devices? Please keep in mind that we are not there in the room with you, and we don't have your hardware. You must help us to understand your experience.

Does the Windows in the dual boot work? (In that case, at least the bootloader installed successfully)

Similar models, issues often common across many models from same vendor. ASUS TUF GAMING FX506L - Install nVidia driver
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2460560
After setting the fast boot option to Auto, it worked!
ASUS FX705GM laptop with an NVIDIA GTX1060
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459714

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

I don't see many of what release or installer you're using.  You mention various flavors and could be using ubiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares depending on release & flavor you mention, but give no clear clues. Please be precise with details (esp. flavor & release details). What options you use at install are also unclear (knowing the installer first would help). Ubuntu Desktop uses ubiquity or ubuntu-desktop-installer depending on release or ISO, Ubuntu Studio or Kubuntu use ubiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares, no clue on kernel stack etc.

Please clearly state what you attempted to install; ie. ISO, as whilst all of Kubuntu, Ubuntu Studio & Ubuntu Desktop are all Ubuntu systems, they do vary in installer & install defaults.. You mention all, but give no release details, nor if using a release that has ISO choice; which ISO you downloaded (the ISO downloaded causes different installer to be used).  You mention an install issue, but haven't said what you're using as far as I see it clearly.  Since this maybe graphics related; kernel stack & details of your video card may also help; you mention model but please give specs too.
